Error handling: catch a TerminatedEvaluation[_]
How to "catch" a _TerminatedEvaluation while calculating.
Supposing that I have two methods to get the result, f[x] and g[x]. Method1 f[x] is very fast but may cause TerminatedEvaluation[_], and method2 g[x] is much slower but safe. So I want to try f[x] first, if TerminatedEvaluation[_] happens, then use g[x].
To test how to catch a TerminatedEvaluation[_], I tried this (to simulate this process, I use a=a+1 to produce TerminatedEvaluation[RecursionLimit])
Catch@Quiet[
    With[{temp = (a = a + 1)(*simulate mathod 1*)}, 
        Print["hello"];
        If[MatchQ[temp, TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"]], 
                Throw[g[x](*method 2*)]
            ]
    ];
    Print["hello"];
  ]

It returns TerminatedEvaluation[RecursionLimit] without even printing "hello". It seems that when TerminatedEvaluation[RecursionLimit] is generated,  all other code will be skipped.
I also tried to use Check and ConfirmQuiet to catch the message $RecursionLimit::reclim, but I failed. So what's the solution?
And, I also find some werid
(*code 1*)
ClearAll[myxx];
With[{temp = (myxx = myxx + 1)},
    If[MatchQ[Print["hello"]; temp, _TerminatedEvaluation], 1, 2]
 ]
(*code 2*)
ClearAll[myxx];
Module[{},
    With[{temp = (myxx = myxx + 1)},
        If[MatchQ[Print["hello"]; temp, _TerminatedEvaluation], 1, 2]
    ]
 ]
(*code 3*)
ClearAll[myxx];
With[{},
    With[{temp = (myxx = myxx + 1)},
        If[MatchQ[Print["hello"]; temp, _TerminatedEvaluation], 1, 2]
    ]
 ]

code1 returns 1 and print "hello" while code 2 returns TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"] and print nothing, code 3 gives same result as code1. It seems that if one create a new "enviroment" (here by Module), TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"] will skip all other code, and I think the result given by the code at the very first is due to the same reason, Why?

Use the second argument of Catch to catch all aborts:
Module[{a, res},
 res = Quiet@Catch[a = a + 1, _];
 If[res === TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"], 
  "Oops. Go to method 2.", "Ok"]
 ]
(* "Oops. Go to method 2." *)

Or use GeneralUtilities`CatchAll.
Quiet@GeneralUtilities`CatchAll[a = a + 1, "Oops!"]
(* "Oops!" *)


<< GeneralUtilities`; ClearAll[a]; GeneralUtilities`CatchAll[Quiet[a = a + 1], "Oops!"]; ClearAll[a]; GeneralUtilities`CatchAll[Quiet[a = a + 1], "Oops!"] returns "Oops!" and Hold[1+a], it seems it only works for the first time?

@Crack-Hu, what is the purpose of your comment? I don't understand it.

Or more targeted: Catch[a = a + 1, _TerminatedEvaluation]. (+1)

@Domen I'm working with "14.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)", for the first time I run this code GeneralUtilities`CatchAll[Quiet[a = a + 1], "Oops!"], it returns "Oops!", but when I try it again, it returns Hold[1 + a], maybe mathematica record the error for accelaration? On the other hand, Catch[, _] do solve my problem, Thank you.
